# project.json Equivalent of InternalsVisibleTo

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, .net-core, project.json

.Net Core's [project.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#copyright) allows configuration of various assembly properties (e.g. title, version, copyright) that a traditional .Net application would define using attributes typically placed in AssemblyInfo.cs (e.g. [AssemblyTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), [AssemblyCopyright](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycopyrightattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), [AssemblyVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)). However, one assembly property I haven't figured out how to set in project.json is [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is there a way to use project.json to indicate that another assembly should have internal visibility into the current project?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No - just put it in `AssemblyInfo.cs` as normal. That's still a perfectly fine place to put assembly attributes. If one isn't created for you in the template you're using, just create your own `AssemblyInfo.cs` file (or any other name, of course). You can put the assembly attributes wherever you want, basically.

Comment: ASP.NET Core projects don't have `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Comment: You now get a lot of `assemblyinfo.cs` auto-generated for you from the package info part of the csproj file. It generates a CS file for you, e.g.: `MyProject\obj\Debug\netstandard1.6\MyProject.AssemblyInfo.cs`. It doesn't do the InternalsVisibleTo though, as before.

Comment: @ChrisS: I certainly wouldn't expect it to add InternalsVisibleTo, of course. The point is that it's fine for the autogenerated file and a manual file to live together.