# Parsing dynamic jsonResult response from API gives "object does not contain definition for X"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, anonymous-types

I am trying to just return a very simple Anonymous object as Json like so:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetJson()
    {
        return Json(new {
            id = 1,
            child = new
            {
                id = 12, 
                name = "woop woop"
            } 
        });
    }
```

Then I have a test case that verify that id = 1

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod4()
    {
        var controller = new ValuesController();
        dynamic result = controller.GetJson();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Value.id);
    }
```

This result in:

> Message: Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod4 threw
>   exception:  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
>   'object' does not contain a definition for 'id'

[image: Image from VS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method returns a `JsonResult` which contains a property `Data` which is your object, so your code should be

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod4()
{
    var controller = new ValuesController();
    dynamic result = controller.GetJson().Data; // returns { id = 1, child = new { id = 12, name = "woop woop" } }
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.id);
}
```

However anonymous objects are `internal` so you also need to make your object visible to your test project. In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of the project containing the `ValuesController` class, add

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourProjectName.UnitTestProject1")]
```

Comment: nice answer. Will be helpful for others also

Comment: The GetJson() does not have .Data, it has .Value. I don't have any AssemblyInfo.cs file. It's a .Net Core 1.1 project.

Comment: Then tag your question properly!

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj/42183749) for the equivalent of `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286152/project-json-equivalent-of-internalsvisibleto)